# Carousel of Images Will Not Advance (HTML/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to have the carousel start immediately upon visiting the page and cycle through a series of images every 2.5 seconds, however it will not advance past the first image. I've looked around here and w3schools but haven't been able to locate where my issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**JavaScript is as follows:**

```
window.onload slideShow();
var i=0;

function slideShow()    {
    window.setInterval("nextSlide()", 2500);
}

function nextSlide()    {
    var images["images/stockton0.jpg",
        "images/stockton1.jpg"
        "images/stockton2.jpg"
        "images/stockton3.jpg"
        "images/stockton4.jpg"
        "images/stockton5.jpg"
        "images/stockton6.jpg"
        "images/stockton7.jpg"
        "images/stockton8.jpg"
        "images/stockton9.jpg"
        "images/stockton10.jpg"]
    var photo = document.getElementByClass("stocktonPics");
    photo.src = images[i];
    i++;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<img class="stocktonPics" src="images/stockton0.jpg" alt="slides">
```

Comment: So 1 - its [getElementsbyClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) which returns an array. Which means it should be `photo[0].src. 2 - You should check your console for errors which will point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good tip is to check the console for errors.

There's nothing wrong with the flow of your code, besides some tips on making it more maintainable, readable, or semantically correct.

You simply forgot an `=` in `window.onload = slideShow;`

And `document.getElementByClass` doesn't exist. You need to use `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` to get an array of elements with that `class`, and finally get its first item with `[0]` like so:

`var photo = document.getElementsByClassName("stocktonPics")[0];`

Note that `slideShow` no longer has the `()` to call it, when `window.onload` is assigned to it. This is because you're assigning `window.onload` to the `slideShow` function, not the result of calling `slideShow()`, which in this case is `undefined`, as nothing is returned.

Your image array should be assigned in this way: `var images = [ a, b, c ]`

The other thing you should do is keep the array of images outside the scope of the function, so you can use it more easily and change it, rather than creating one (if you don't count optimizations) ever time the function is called. And lastly, `window.setInterval( a, b )` can take either a string that will be `eval()`ed (or equivalent to it), which is what you did, or a function itself. In your case, what you want is simply the function: `window.setInterval( nextSlide, 2500 )`.

Here's the final full code:

```
var i=0;
var images=[
      "images/stockton0.jpg",
      "images/stockton1.jpg",
      "images/stockton2.jpg",
      "images/stockton3.jpg",
      "images/stockton4.jpg",
      "images/stockton5.jpg",
      "images/stockton6.jpg",
      "images/stockton7.jpg",
      "images/stockton8.jpg",
      "images/stockton9.jpg",
      "images/stockton10.jpg" ];

function slideShow() {
    window.setInterval( nextSlide, 2500);
}

function nextSlide() {
    var photo = document.getElementsByClassName("stocktonPics")[0];
    photo.src = images[i];
    i++;
}

window.onload = slideShow;
```

Comment: The console appears to be clear. I cleared my history/cache as well, but no luck... Thanks for the catch on the '='

Comment: @gothamprince Not with all those syntax and type errors

Comment: @towc Thanks! I'll give those edits a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: @Andreas is it...? oh damn it XD

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClass` 
method is will get a like array elements object,

so, you should use `[0]` to get the first element object and set src attr.

`var pics = document.getElementsByClassName("stocktonPics")`

It's a like array elements object

`var firstPic = document.getElementsByClassName("stocktonPics")[0]`

It's a element object

```js
let i = 0;
const images = ["images/stockton0.jpg",
                "images/stockton1.jpg",
                "images/stockton2.jpg",
                "images/stockton3.jpg",
                "images/stockton4.jpg",
                "images/stockton5.jpg",
                "images/stockton6.jpg",
                "images/stockton7.jpg",
                "images/stockton8.jpg",
                "images/stockton9.jpg",
                "images/stockton10.jpg"];
const stockton = document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0];

const slideShow = () => {
    window.setInterval(nextSlide, 2500);
}

const nextSlide = () => {
    stockton.src = images[i];
    if(i >= images.length - 1) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
    console.log(i, stockton)
}
slideShow()
```

```html
<img class="example">
```

Comment: there's no reason to drive the asker into es6. Your full code doesn't include setting the `src` anywhere, and there's no such thing as `.getElementByClass`